# How can I have the posts from one word press blog show on the presentation page of another word press site

Tags: posts, multisite, customization, rss, blog

I am using the Tempera 1.2.2 theme with presentation page enabled (http://worldofmagictravel.com) and curently the blog posts that are showing on the presentation page are from  a blog category within that site.

I also have a separate blog that ties in with the site (http://worldofmagictravelblog.com) How can I replace the latests post on the sites presentation page with the posts written on the separate blog site.

I thought about using some sort of RSS feed pluggin but, I do not know how I would insert the widget into the presentation page. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
David

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using WP Multisite? Or this is two separate WP installations? If multisite, do you have the capability to create/edit the theme files?

Comment: I am using two separate WP installations.

Comment: I would consider using WP multisite if you're sharing a lot of content, that way you could use switch_to_blog()/restore_current_blog() to easily pull the posts. Otherwise RSS feeds are probably your best bet. There are several plugins that can be used to achieve this. RSS Post Importer (which gtrout mentions below is one) and assign them to a category. Then you could either depend on your existing category archive template (.com/category/import-category), or create a page template that loops though those imported posts of that category.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a plugin that automatically creates posts from an RSS feed. For instance, the plugin [RSS Post Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/), should do what you want. It will allow you to import posts to a specific category, which you can then display on the presentation page.